# What is the difference between "open?id=" and "spreadsheets/d/" / "drive/folders/" in Google Drive?

Tags: url, hyperlink, google-drive-api

I don't actually have a problem, but I am very curious, why sharing URLs are different in "Get Shareable Link" and "Share..." buttons.

For example, I want to share one folder.
When I get URL from "Get Shareable Link", I get this:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Tgz6ltC4WKmgbrRYNhd3r0hAjS7C_K2l
```

but, if I get URL from "Share...", I get this:

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Tgz6ltC4WKmgbrRYNhd3r0hAjS7C_K2l?usp=sharing
```

Well, I know some things about the URL in the second link: The `usp=` must be source parameter, that where the link came from, and yes, this is sharing. It came from sharing ("Share..."). And also there are may other parameters:

```
usp=drive_web
usp=direct_url
```

[Google Drive Links URL format and query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624321/google-drive-links-url-format-and-query-parameters)

And there are also parameters before `usp=`: "edit, view: these parameters tell the browser the priority that which type of access to go into if this access type is accessible. So, if the link has "edit" parameter but the user don't have permission to edit the file/folder, then automaticlly it will be redirected into "view" permission mode.

https://learninginhand.com/blog/google-document-url-tricks

Well, these are king of understandable, but my question is this:

Why these two links have different starting?

1. `https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Tgz6......`
2. `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Tgz6......`

I know that this is file/folder ID: `1Tgz6ltC4WKmgbrRYNhd3r0hAjS7C_K2l`, but what is the point of these differences in these links?

why the first one has `open?id=` and the second one has `drive/folders/`, why? Which one is better to use in which situations? If both are fine in any situation, then why are they two? What is the point of it? You know, I get the point of URL ending parameters (`usp=` and stuff), but I don't get the point of different URLs which work kinda absolutely the same way: to share/get file/folder.

There is also another example:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vY7tQaNt3Vnkaxy-5Lbn1ImOfTiTC5bPk8mRZLqBOsE

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vY7tQaNt3Vnkaxy-5Lbn1ImOfTiTC5bPk8mRZLqBOsE
```

What's the point of these two guys:

1. `open?id=`
2. `spreadsheets/d/`

Don't they just do the same thing: to build the URL? So, why the same folder/file is represented by two different URLs? Why there is not just one URL (of course with ending parameters: `usp=` and stuff. the ending parameters are quick understandable).

Comment: Both links are fine for edit and also for view. both links work in fact absolutely similarly. But what is the difference?

1) https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Tgz6..........
2) https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Tgz6..........

Why should I use the second one when the first link is shorter? I mean: Why we call an adsress (a street) two names? A street normally has just one name, for example "Broadway". Why should we give this street a second name? Broadway and Codeway? Why should we give a street two names? Isn't one name enough?